# How to remove unused dependencies in Python 3

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management, python-packaging, python-venv

I'm new to Python 3. I'm using `python3 -m venv` to create virtual environments and `pip` to install packages in small projects.

I would like to know if there is a way to manage dependencies that are no longer used after changes in these projects.

So that I don't need to remove the venv and recreate/reinstall all dependencies each time.

E.g.: some `pip` command or Python module that reads the entry file of these projects and review the dependencies, removing the unused ones from my virtual environment.

Comment: Tools like *pipreqs* and *pigar* should allow you to list the dependencies that are used. From there it should be feasible to deduct the dependencies that are not used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does `pipreqs` and `pigar` let me differentiate between my project's dependencies and its own dependencies?

Comment: I assume yes. They analyze the code of the project to determine the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

`pipreqs`, indicated by [sinoroc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11138259/sinoroc) in the comments, solves the problem.

```bash
# removing requirements.txt and uninstalling all packages
rm requirements.txt
pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)
pip install pipreqs
pipreqs .
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

```bash
# using requirements.txt to uninstall packages
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt
pip install pipreqs
pipreqs . --force
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: With `pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)` you remove everything installed. This is almost equivalent to removing the venv and recreating/reinstalling all dependencies each time. Exactly what you tried to avoid. What is the advantage?

Comment: "So that I don't need to remove the venv and recreate/reinstall all dependencies each time."  `pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)` **does not remove the venv, only the packages installed**; `pipreqs` installs only the required dependencies and recreates 'requirements.txt'. This solves the issue.

Comment: It's basically a clean-up of the venv, and for me it works even better than uninstalling packages using the old 'requirements.txt'; all I have to do after it is reinstalling some dev dependencies.